# Is there a way to add a custom icon to map's Mapbox?

Tags: flutter, mapbox, mapbox-gl, flutter-dependencies, mapbox-marker

I might have skipped some documentation about `flutter_map` plugin, but I could not find any way to use a simple `.png` image as a custom icon for a `Mapbox` marker?

Should I maybe use another `plugin`? Or is there a way to do what I attempted to do?

Answer (score 3):

You can do that with the mapbox_gl plugin by calling

```
MapboxMapController.addSymbol(
  SymbolOptions(
    geometry: LatLng(latitude, longitude),
    iconImage: iconImage,
  );
```

You can use the name of one of your asset images as iconImage or the name of one of the icons included in your style (e.g. 'defaultMarker' should be included in every style).
There is also an example of this in the place_symbol.dart file of the plugin's example project.